# How to design UI for listviewitem

Tags: c#, winforms

In winform, I want to create a listview displaying like this:

[image: each row has a picture on the left, on the right it has Name upper and Phone below]

I know in c#, listviewitem is only able to add text only, but is there a way or another component that can solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

`UserControl` for per person added in a `FlowLayoutPanel` can get you the desired appearance. Design your `UserControl` with image and couple of labels to make the single item appearance and add them in `FlowLayoutPanel`. You're done.

That said, It would be easy to do this in WPF if it is an option.

Comment: It would just not be easy in WPF. It would be `too` easy in WPF.